# Updating my adapter in onCreateView instead of onResume

Tags: java, android

I'm currently checking if my adapter is empty or not and then setting the visibility of my `TextView` accordingly, as shown below:

```
DBManager dbManager = new DBManager(getActivity());
dbManager.open();
Cursor cursor = dbManager.fetch();
adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), cursor);
gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
if (gridView.getAdapter().isEmpty()) {
    textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

dbManager.close();
cursor.close();
```

This is working fine, but I'm calling this in my `onCreateView` of my `Fragment` and `onResume` which feels unnecessary. I was thinking of changing it to this:

```
public class FragmentAdapter3 extends Fragment {
    private GridView gridView;
    private TextView textView;
    private MyAdapter adapter;
    View v;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v = View.inflate(getContext(),R.layout.fragment_main_adapter3, null);

        gridView = v.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
        textView = v.findViewById(R.id.textView);

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener((parent, view, position, viewId) -> {           
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), ProfilePage.class);            
            startActivity(intent);

        });

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        DBManager dbManager = new DBManager(getActivity());
        dbManager.open();
        Cursor cursor = dbManager.fetch();
        adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity(), cursor);
        gridView.setAdapter(adapter);
        if (gridView.getAdapter().isEmpty()) {
            textView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        dbManager.close();
        cursor.close();

    }
```

Is there any reason why I can't call the above in my `onResume` only?

I understand that `onCreateView` is only called once, that is why I initialize my views in `onCreateView` and then set the adapter etc. in `onResume`.

Comment: what is your goal?

Comment: You're also using different adapter in `gridView.setAdapter(ad);` inside `onResume`

Comment: @RahulKhurana I edited my question, it was a typo, my mistake. "what is your goal?" - I don't want to call the same code twice.

Comment: Then use only the `If` and `else` statement in the onResume method